# Pipelines: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.4

Tags: android, gradle, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have updated top-level build.gradle file :
from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

And now cant build project on Bitbucket-Pipelines:
Error is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/app/build.gradle' line: 1
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 37s
```

Comment: Which command do you use to start the build? It should be something like `./gradlew build`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.4.
> ```

The statement itself says the solution

Please change inside
project>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Comment: check my edited answer. Change `gradle-4.10.zip` to `gradle-4.10-all.zip`

Comment: please post the error after doing above.(try `gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`)

Comment: I too had the same issue. But couldn't solve it.
Actually, in my **distributionsUrl** it is **5.4.1**. Still it shows that current version is **4.10.2** and failed to build the **Release apk**>

Comment: @ABHIMANGALMS I have the very similar problem to yours. Can you please let me know how you resolved it?

Comment: @vinayManeti What I did was, just copied all the new codes ( from the current project file) to the old project file (backup of that project). Only that solved my issue. If you have a backup file which was working perfectly then use this technique. So that we may not lose our time. Thank you.